# Deserialize IndexingPolicy(Azure Cosmos DB) from JSON

Tags: json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to deserialize from a json IndexingPolicy in order to update the Azure Cosmos DB.
Although IndexingPolicy and all its inner class are subclasses of JsonSerializable, it fails to be deserialized.

Index is one of the inner class of IndexingPolicy and is lack of empty constructor. Therefore, the deserialization fails. However, I find it hard to believe that the developers of the framework haven't tested it properly.

I have tried two ways to deserialize,

```
    var jsonString = @"{
      'indexingMode': 'consistent',
      'automatic': true,
      'includedPaths': [
        {
          'path': '/PartitionKey/?',
          'indexes': [
            {
              'kind': 'Range',
              'dataType': 'String',
              'precision': -1
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      'excludedPaths': [
        {
          'path': '/*'
        }
      ]
    }";
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions()
    {
        IgnoreNullValues = true,
        IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true,
        WriteIndented = true,
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        AllowTrailingCommas = false,
        MaxDepth = 1000,
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
    };
    IndexingPolicy index = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IndexingPolicy>(jsonString, options);
```

And also by LoadFrom() method,

```
        IndexingPolicy ip = new IndexingPolicy();
        using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(jsonString)))
        {
            ip.LoadFrom(reader);
        }
```

To be on the safe side I also tried with this JSON

```
{
      "indexingMode": 0,
      "automatic": true,
      "includedPaths": [
        {
          "path": "/PartitionKey/?",
          "indexes": [
            {
              "kind": 1,
              "dataType": 1,
              "precision": -1
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "excludedPaths": [
        {
          "path": "/*"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the default Newtonsoft.Json settings works without issues:

```
string serializedPolicy = @"{
  ""indexingMode"": 0,
  ""automatic"": true,
  ""includedPaths"": [
    {
      ""path"": ""/PartitionKey/?"",
      ""indexes"":[{""dataType"":""Number"",""precision"":-1,""kind"":""Hash""}]
    }
  ],
  ""excludedPaths"": [
    {
       ""path"": ""/*""
    }
  ]
}";
IndexingPolicy policy = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IndexingPolicy>(serializedPolicy);
```

Keep in mind that the index definition you are using in your example seems to be incorrect, the `dataType` and `kind` are numbers, which seem to have to be the actual names.

Comment: This really solves the issue. Thanks!
Do you know why it works in Newtonsoft.Json but not in System.Text.Json?
For your comment about `dataType` and `kind`, as you can see in the original post, I have tried the two options :)

Comment: If I add `Index.Range(DataType.String, -1);` before `ip.LoadFrom(reader);` it works fine. However it doesn't work with `JsonSerializer.Deserialize`.

Comment: It doesn't work with System.Text.Json because the SDK is currently tied to Newtonsoft.Json and these are SDK classes (not user data classes) so the are using Newtonsoft.Json decorators and converters, reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Resource/Settings/IndexingPolicy.cs